# Erratic slidetoggle jquery behavior with nested divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

Looks for some help with my layout, where I have rows of divs hidden on page load, which slide up and down after the headings are clicked. This is done with jquery `slidetoggle`.

For some reason, only some of the sliding divs open/close smoothly. Others will snap open and after closing, leaves a space that occupies the height of the hidden div.

I've created a fiddle which shows this (at least in Chrome and FF): https://jsfiddle.net/6cLk2a9z/1/

My HTML include headers with `class=trigger` and hidden divs with `class=hidden`. A click event on the `trigger` heading slides the divs like this:

```
// slide trigger 
$(".hidden").hide();

$("div.trigger").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(250);
});
```

I have some CSS to nest the divs into blocks and columns like this:

```
.grayback {
    background-color: lightblue;

}
.yellback {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
.greenback {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.trigger{
    background-color: gray;

}
.container {
  border-style: none;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #2F4D63;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
} 

.content {
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  color: black;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  min-height: 125px;
  min-width: 32%;
}
```

Has anyone seen this effect with slideToggle? I've tried changing how I call the slideToggle method with not luck. I've tried different builds of jQuery with no difference. For some reason, IE10+ works fine, but FF and Chrome both show the wonky stuff. Maybe it's a problem with my CSS? But I can't seem to pin it down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem - the issue was with the way the CSS on the `.container` class was displayed.

When I changed the CSS from

```
 display: inline;
  float: left;
```

to

```
 display: inline-block;
  vertical-algin: bottom;
```

The display error was resolved in both FF and Chrome.

To be honest, I don't know why this worked, but after some deep diving through SO, I pieced together a solution from similar wonky slideToggle issues elsewhere.

Anyone who can educate on why this worked and why my original CSS worked fine until recent upgrades, your comments would be appreciated!